# Docker for Windows with existing hyper-v virtual machine

Tags: hyper-v, docker-for-windows

I have the following setup:

A Windows 10 Pro Laptop ("Win10Laptop") that has a Windows 10 Pro VM ("Win10VM") running on Hyper-V. I have created an nginx container by running the following command on the host machine:

docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx

While the container is running I can access http://localhost from Win10Laptop and this works fine. My question is what do I need to configure to access nginx from Win10VM? Win10VM has only one network adaptor which is configured to use the "External" Vswitch connected to my Wifi interface.

Let me know if you need any more details. I've tried all sorts and can't figure it out!

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect to the IP the VM has acquired on the External switch. Run `ipconfig` inside the VM to see what IP it has, then open `http://<vm-ip>` from your host.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Connecting to http://10.51.108.200 (The VM's IP address) gives me a connection refused error but connecting to http://10.51.108.190 (The Win10Laptop's IP) gives me the nginx landing page. So in theory this is going out onto the network then back to Win10Laptop. Is this how it's supposed to work? This is all from the Win10VM btw. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, the Docker is on the host. Me read bad. Yes, if the container is on the host, then Docker is bridging the *host* network port 80 to the container port 80 (the nginx). So you can access it by the host IP, including from the VM (which being `External` it accesses the host as any other network device).

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. Marked as answer :)